# How do you actually write out the terms in a Cauchy sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, intuition, cauchy-sequences

For example for $\epsilon>0$ there exist $N$ such $n,m>N$ implies $|s_m-s_n|<\epsilon$. I understand that intuitively, we don't need to know a certain limit and thus this definition for convergent sequences ends up being useful. But, I saw a proof that wrote out the terms like this: $|s_m-s_n|=|(s_m-s_{m-1})+(s_{m-1}-s_{m-2})+...+(s_{n-1}-s_n)|$ and I found it a bit strange since I assumed it was: $|(s_m-s_n)|=$(sequence of $s_m$)$-$(sequence of $s_n$). But upon writing this question, did they actually do the plus and minus trick? Such that it's only true because the insides get canceled out and you end up with $|s_m-s_n|$? Is my intuitive definition correct, in the least?

Comment: The last term should be "sn+1-sn"

Comment: Yes, you are right, I wrote this out fast.

Comment: In fact, the trick is that almost all terms cancel out. This is used quite often, if series have to be calculated.

Comment: So the insides do cancel and makes  sm-sn?

Comment: Exactly that...

Comment: In metric spaces with the least upper bound property cauchy sequences *do* converge so if we do want to find the limit so the plus minus trick helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
You can always do such manipulations. 
But your assumption is incorrect, check the proper definition of cauchy sequences find the error.
What it implies is after a certain N, the following "terms" of the sequence get arbitrarily close to each other.
 the terms inside the modulus are m'th and n'th terms of the sequence for m,n>=N, some natural number depending upon choice of epsilon.